# Problem with 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header' with express and react application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm going to do a project in Node/Express just to level up in javascript, but I have a problem with 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'. I can't do a get request from the front and I don't know why. I have see in the other post but nothing work.

this is my index.js :

```js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('./config');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');

mongoose.connect(config.DATABASE_URL, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true });
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'Error connecting to the database'));
db.once('open', function () {
    console.log("Connection to the database successfully");
});

require('./models/Partner');

const index = express();
index.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
  });
index.use(bodyParser.json());
index.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

index.use(config.ROOT_API + '/', require('./routes/homeRouter'));
index.use(config.ROOT_API + '/partner', require('./routes/partnerRouter'));
index.use(morgan('dev'));
index.listen((config.HOST), () => console.log('Started on port ' + config.HOST));
```

I added this to try to make it work, but obviously it doesn't work ..

```js
    index.use((req, res, next) => {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        next();
      });
```

Thank you for you answer ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
const allowCors = function (req, res, next) {
console.log("Came to cros");

res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X- 
Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, 
PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
next();
};
```

And try adding Bellow

```
index.use(allowCors);
```

After

```
index.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Comment: same problem :

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://185.216.25.31:8080/api/partner/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Have you added as index.use(allowCors); ??

Comment: yes, after index.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

Comment: Is console.log("Came to cros"); working on your console?

Comment: Make sure it is index.use(allowCors); not app.use(allowCors);

Comment: Try restarting your application in production environment.. make sure your app is alive in production without amy crashes.. Trace your log and check whether your console.log() inside cors function is working

Answer (score 0):

if you need just for testing
go to `run` ( `windows+R`)

write `chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security`

and try again in your new browser which opened

Hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your express (index.js)

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('./config');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors') // Add this package do npm i cors first
const morgan = require('morgan');

mongoose.connect(config.DATABASE_URL, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true });
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'Error connecting to the database'));
db.once('open', function () {
    console.log("Connection to the database successfully");
});

require('./models/Partner');

const index = express();
// Use the Middlware as below
index.use(cors());
index.use(bodyParser.json());
index.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

index.use(config.ROOT_API + '/', require('./routes/homeRouter'));
index.use(config.ROOT_API + '/partner', require('./routes/partnerRouter'));
index.use(morgan('dev'));
index.listen((config.HOST), () => console.log('Started on port ' + config.HOST));
```

For futher reference look at this [link](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)